# Is it possible to set a rate limiting rule along preconfigured WAF rules for the same backend service in Cloud Armor?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I have a policy for a backend service with several preconfigured WAF rules. Also there is a rate limiting rule. If I set the preconfigured WAF rules with higher priority, it will only evaluate those and never the rate limiting rule regardless if the application is under a flood attack with many "legitimate" requests. On the other hand if the rate limiting rule is set with higher priority, it will block flood attacks, but none of the lower priority preconfigured WAF rules will be evaluated.

I have been testing this policy with [siege](https://linux.die.net/man/1/siege) and [GoTestWaf](https://github.com/wallarm/gotestwaf). The results are as follows:

- If the **rate limiting rule is of higher priority**, requests sent by siege are blocked when they hit the set threshold, but GoTestWaf stops with error *"**WAF was not detected**. Please use the '--blockStatusCodes' or '--blockRegex' flags. Use '--help' for additional info. Baseline attack status code: 200"*
- If the **rate limiting rule is set on lower priority, requests sent by siege are never blocked**, but GoTestWaf detects the firewall, conducts the tests and malicious requests are blocked as expected.

Preconfigured WAF rules are [these](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/waf-rules#crs-3.3), and the rate limiting rule is set as the following:

```
gcloud compute security-policies rules create 10000 \
--project=<GCP project> \
--security-policy=<Policy name> \
--expression="true" \
--action=rate-based-ban \
--rate-limit-threshold-count=120 \
--rate-limit-threshold-interval-sec=60 \
--ban-duration-sec=300 \
--conform-action=allow \
--exceed-action=deny-404 \
--enforce-on-key=IP
```

What is going on?
Is there any other way to have both preconfigured WAF rules and a rate limiting rule targeting the same backend?

Comment: Where are you set your rate limit? In the Load Balancer?

Comment: The rate limiting rule is set on the same Cloud Armor policy as the other rules

Comment: 1) I would not return 404. Instead, return 429 which means `Too Many Requests`. 2) The rule priority is 10,000. Is that a lower priority (bigger number) or higher priority (lower number) than the other rules meaning is this rule being ignored because another rule took precedence? 3) In the real world, the threshold count is too low, and threshold interval is too short. You can see a burst from a web browser if the client has several pages to your site loaded. Some browsers throw away inactive tabs and then refresh once the tabs are reactivated. Everything else looks good.

Comment: As I've described in the original question, if the rate limiting rule is set on higher priority the others are never evaluated and vice versa. So I've it tested both ways: on higher and lower priority. Regarding points n° 1 and 3, the rate limiting rule configurations are set that way just for testing. Thanks for the suggestions though, I will set a more appropiate status code.

Answer (score 0):

While setting any rate limiting options then it’s [mandatory](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/securityPolicies/addRule#:%7E:text=Requires%20rateLimitOptions%20to%20be%20set) to specify the  flags. If you are using the normal policy where Allowing  or Denying IP’s then it’s an optional but if specifically setting the rate limiting options for cloud armor security policies then these require rate limiting options to be set.

[Rule evaluation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview#eval-order) order is determined by rule priority. When your traffic rate is under or equal to the rate_limit_threshold, then the requests follow the conform-action, which is always an allowed action. The request is authorized by security policy and allowed to reach its destination. Meanwhile the traffic rate exceeds the specified rate_limit_threshold, Google Cloud Armor applies the exceed_action, which can be either denied or redirected, for requests over the limit for the rest of the threshold interval. For more information follow this [Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rate-limiting-overview) Or else you can also use [Google Cloud Armor Managed Protection.](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/managed-protection-overview#standard_versus_plus)

Comment: I don't understand the first paragraph completely; What is the "normal policy"? I've expandend on the rules details in my question. The rate liting rule is just another rule on the same policy as the other preconfigured WAF rules.
From the second paragraph I understand that if a request follow the conform action it will go to the backend service and my app without being evaluated by other rules, even if it is malicious? So there is not a way to protect my app against flood and malicious requests at the same time using Cloud Armor? (my orginial question)